# Magento: frontend text field that updates the product price?

Tags: magento, frontend

I have no idea how to do this, this does need to be added to a working store with normal products, I am ok at making an new template to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom magento module with a controller

Then create a save action in your SavepriceController.php

```
public function saveAction(){
    $websites = Mage::app()->getWebsites();

    $product_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('product_id');
    // need to validate price here
    $price = $this->getRequest()->getParam('price');

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id)
    if($product->getId()){
        $product->setPrice($price)->save();
    }
}
```

Then add a text field to your frontend page

```
 <form action='http://site.com/modulename/Saveprice/save' method='post'>
      <input type='hidden' name='product_id' value='add product id here' />
      <input type='text' name='price' />
      <input type='submit' value='submit' />
 </form>
```